# Two drop down option lists in a form using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, drop-down-menu

I have a problem with two drop down lists ( options ) in a form. 
They both work separately but together they don't work at all. It's like they are canceling each other out or something.
 If anyone can help me then I'll be truly grateful. Here's the code with the problem...
 JS fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/wemdragon/3Uz/

Comment: What is the intent of your script? Looking at the fiddle, are you expecting both messages on error to be displayed?

Comment: Both error messages should work if not selected. But the options values don't calculate when there together

Comment: It looks to be that way because you are overwriting the previous HTML of the element instead of concatenating when you do `error.html('options 2!')`

Comment: Update - So changing the if statement to else if has fixed the error meassages issue. But doesnt fix the calculation, does anybody else have an idea on whats going wrong?

Comment: The cascading set of if/else statements will never hit your calculation block, since the else is container after the checks for no selection, 1, or 2, on `option2`.

Comment: I just get a 404 error on the fiddle page...not sure why

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple problems.  First off, `.val()` gets a string rather than an int, so `if ('0')` will return true.  Therefore, `options 2!` is always emitted no matter what you have selected for the second option.  You need to update that conditional to check `if (second.val() != 0)` (this will coerce '0' and 0 and return true -- you can also get more specific or simply use an empty string as the `value` instead, which is probably preferred).

Second of all, your calculation code is never reached since it is the `else` in the chain of `if`s that cover all possible combination of selections.  You need some other flag to check that the calculation should be done, or make it a function that is called when a valid selection is made.